# Update Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 to Ubuntu Gnome 16.10

Tags: 16.04, gnome, 16.10

I'm currently running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 that I originally got from here:
https://ubuntugnome.org/

How can I upgrade to Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 without losing files? I know I can do:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

But will that switch from Ubuntu gnome to regular ubuntu?

I want to go to Ubuntu Gnome 16.10, NOT Ubuntu 16.10.

(I know if that happened going to Gnome desktop again would be possible, but trying to avoid that if I could)

Sidenote: First time posting on here, so if this is in error please let me know! Completely unintentional.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, according to the 16.10 UbuntuGNOME [documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/YakketyYak/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME), GNOME has been upgraded to version **3.2** from **3.18**, as seen [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/YakketyYak/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME#Select_GNOME_changes_since_Ubuntu_16.04_LTS). My assumption would be that you would already have to just install 16.10 normally and install GNOME post-installation, but especially with the update of the GNOME version itself, I think the best way would be to just upgrade to the official 16.10 version and re-install GNOME from there.

Comment: **EDIT/ADDITION TO MY PREVIOUS POST**: I found a [post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1746966) that could be useful to your situation.

Comment: Sorry I'm responding so late. Thanks so much for the help!